# Unity - Increasing timescale has strange effect on NavMeshAgent velocity

Tags: c#, unity-game-engine

I have a BlendTree that controls my Animation for Idle/walking/running. This is controlled by variable `speedPercent`.

For some reason, when I increase TimeScale above 1 while standing still, `agent.velocity` starts adding a value to the y-axis, ie `(0, 1.6, 0)`, causing magnitude to return a value.

Everything is managed by default NavMeshAgent methods (`SetDestination` for example).

```
void Update()
{
    float speedPercent = agent.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed;
    animator.SetFloat("speedPercent", speedPercent);
}
```

Comment: Coming from your last question, does `float speedPercent = (agent.hasPath ? agent.velocity.magnitude : 0f) / agent.speed;` help?

Comment: Adding this check, and adding an else that sets speedpercent to 0 does fix it. But I would like to udnerstand why this is happening. Why does my agent get a y-velocity while standing still if I increase the timescale?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Unity's `NavMeshAgent` can have unexpected values for the velocity when it doesn't have a path. I am not sure why, but it seems to be a commonplace issue.

I would recommend a workaround: use a ternary operator to use `0f` instead of `agent.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed` if the agent isn't currently pathing:

```
void Update()
{
    float speedPercent = agent.hasPath ? agent.velocity.magnitude / agent.speed : 0f;
    animator.SetFloat("speedPercent", speedPercent);
}
```